# Cypress not getting required selector

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am trying to set up a function in Cypress to get a selector but its not working

```
class carPage {
model = 'model'
getModel = () => this.get(this.model)
get = (key) => cy.get(`cy-data-${key}`); }
```

This should grab the selector on screen which has cy-data-model.

In my test:

```
import car from "../../helpers/carPage";

describe('Tests', () => {

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
    }        
);

it("should get car text", function () {

    car.getModel(); 
 }
```

but I am getting the error Property 'getModel' does not exist on type 'typeof carPage'.ts(2339)

It works if I create static methods, but I don't understand why the above wont work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code look like below ?

carPage.ts

```
class carPage {
    model = 'model'
    getModel = () => this.get(this.model)
    get = (key) => cy.get(`cy-data-${key}`); 
}

export default carPage;
```

Test file:

```
import car from "../../helpers/carPage";
...
car.getModel();
```

If so, the variable car in your test file reference the class carPage.
To use instance field you have to create new instance of the class first

```
import CarPage from "../../helpers/carPage";
...
const car = new CarPage();
car.getModel();
```